# Push view of storyboard in accessorybutton tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard, uitableview

I have storyboard named "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard" and it has 2 views. The first view has a table cell with disclosure button. I can drag drop the table cell to other view and show the view, but I need to do it programmatically only when user click on accessory button without using segue. The name of 2 views are RootViewController and ProviderLookupViewController. Currently I have tried this code but doesnt work, it throws error when I click on the accessory button on the cell. Commented lines are the other things that I tried

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                                  bundle:nil];
   // ProviderLookupViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProviderLookupViewController"];
    UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProviderLookupViewController"];
     [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: can you add the error message?

Comment: You say `The name of 2 views...` Do you mean UIViewController? By the way, using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` requires that an identifier is set for your view controller (Utilities / Identity inspector)

Comment: Yes, first one is the RootViewController, identifier is set. And getting error, Program received signal:SIGABRT

Comment: Have you try to replace `bundle:nil` by `bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]` ?

Comment: The error was cause of the identifier name, there was a spelling mistake, silly me. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give storyboard id [image: StoryBoard id] as ProviderLookupViewController in your scenario and tick use storyboard Id then

```
ProviderLookupViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProviderLookupViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Note:ProviderLookupViewController is your identifier.

Comment: I cant find this option, in which view is this available, currently I clicked on the 2nd view with class:ProviderLookupViewController and under identity it only has object ID and label. I am using xcode 4.2

Comment: are u using storyboard?? sorry replace uiviewcontroller with ur view name i.e ProviderLookupViewController

Comment: then,    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
ProviderLookupViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProviderLookupViewController"];

[self presentViewController: vc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: The error was cause of the identifier name, there was a spelling mistake. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 3):

If I am correct:

1) From your question it seems that you have a story board with two view controller, the first one is a UITableViewController and the other a subclass of UIViewController.

2) You want to present the second view  when the user clicks the disclosure button.

Given that you use a storyboard instead of nib files, I recommend that you use a segue, it will solve you problem without writing code.

A table view cell can have two segues, one if you select the cell and another if you select the accesory button. Control drag from from the accessory button to the second view controller instead of doing the control drag from the cell and when the menu appears you have to select an option below Accesory action instead of below Selection Segue

[image]

The prototype cell of the table view has to have the disclosure accessory enable. Do it from the utilities pane (the right one). Accessory can't be none do this. In the picture accessoy is Detail disclosure.

[image]

The utilities pane also let's you do the segue. Use accessory action, though, teh picture is from one of my projects.

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the Accessory Action option when I control drag from the cell. Am I missing anything? I'm using Xcode  4.2

Comment: You have to convert the cell to a discloure type and then the accessory will apeear on the cell. Once it appears, control drag from the accessory.

Comment: @Gamerlegend I have added a picture and more explanation to answer your question

Comment: I've tried this, button I'm not able to click on the accessory, it clicks the whole cell, any ideas?

Comment: @Gamerlegend Post a picture of your storyboard. Also you could completely close Xcode and open it again. Some times this trick solves issues with the storyboard.

Comment: I just checked, its not available with 4.2 you must be using 4.6 or higher version of 4.2 Anyway I got the solution. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Gamerlegend Please post your solution as an update for other people using Xcode 4.2. so that the community can benefit from this question.

Answer (score -1):

Create a segue in IB from one view controller to another. Add some identificator to segue and just use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeSegueName" sender:someObject];
```

Comment: Gamerlegend has specified `without using segue`

Comment: He did not point why. As I understand he does not know that he can use segue call from the code